# ArcGIS Server 10.0 - error publishing map service - 'wait timeout interval has elapsed'

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server, map-service, publishing

I am trying to publish a map service from an .mxd on ArcGIS Server 10.0, and I am getting this error in the Server Manager log:

'Configuration service.MapServer can not be added. A request to obtain a free ServerContext has failed because the Wait Timeout Interval has elapsed.'

I do not understand this error, as I have not yet set the parameters for a map service instance?  Is there some other setting I should modify in Server Manager?

Comment: There is a publishing timeout on the server, but it's pretty hard to reach. How fast does the error happen after you attempt to publish?

Comment: If I am restarting an existing service, I receive the error after 1 minute (the default wait time).  I tried restarting the SOC Monitor and Server Object Manager in Windows Services, which worked, but now I am getting the same error when I try to restart the map services and I get an error 'Windows could not stop the ArcGIS SOC Monitor service ...Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion' in the Services window.